# Сломался dpkg после do-release-upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

После прерывания `sudo do-release-upgrade` при попытке что-то установить через apt идет следующее сообщение:

`Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

В выводе `sudo dpkg -s dpkg` в консоли (а конкретно в графе Status) выводится следующее:

`Status: install reinstreq half-installed`

Не работают в том числе и команды `sudo apt install -f`, `sudo apt --fix-broken install` и `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force dpkg`

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае (не обещаю, что сработает у вас) мой dpkg отвечал на команды, таким образом я подумал, что он все еще может устанавливать пакеты.

Я скачал с https://packages.ubuntu.com актуальную версию dpkg **для релиза, на который я пытался обновиться** в формате **.deb**, и установил его через "сломанный" dpkg в систему поверх старого, используя команду `sudo dpkg -i (путь к скачанному файлу dpkg)`, после чего тот начал исправно работать.